# Sending query params forth to another page with POST in Node JS and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-applications

This is the issue I'm facing:

I have multiple consecutive web pages where I hold the same id in the query params and send it forth from one to the next due to various reasons. All is fine when passing this param with GET routes. However, the third page (which has the query param as well) has a short form and POST method, which redirects to the fourth page at the end. Something like this:

```
app.post("/third", function(req, res){
   req.body.id //returns undefined, but should not

   some code here

   res.redirect("/fourth?id="+id); //how i want to pass the param on
});
```

Whichever I use, req.body or req.query or req.params, I can never access the id 'abcd' from

```
web-app/third?id=abcd
```

and add it to the fourth page query params, I always get undefined.

Am I doing this wrong? Still quite new to Node JS and Express and everything to do with web-apps, so my logic might be off. I've searched Google, but due to my inexperience most of the posts were unhelpful for me. How to send the params when I have a POST method and cannot access the param from anywhere except the page holding the form query itself?

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit:**

How the front-end looks like:

```
<form action="/third" method="post">
...
a few inputs here 
....
<input type="submit" rel="next" value="To signing" class="button" 
id="nextbutton">                        
<a onclick="setUrl();" rel="prev" class="button" id="cancelbutton">Previous page</a>
</form>
```

/third is the current page, /fourth the next

Comment: Can you post how you are posting from your front-end?

Comment: Updated main post as you asked

Comment: And the id input, any chance you can add that as well to the code?

Comment: And is the /web-app/ a different sub route or is it just a replacement for localhost?

Comment: the id isn't an input on this page, it is received from the page prior to the third in the query params. Like I wrote:  I hold the same id in the query params and send it forth from one to the next due to various reasons. And it's a replacement for localhost at the moment.

Comment: See my answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you mean now. Your url which you are POST'ing the form from contains a query parameter in the URL. That's the parameter which you can't access to. Well - that parameter is not in the POST parameters, it's not in the form. So you have 2 options.

1. When you're outputting the `/third` view with your GET request you should add that query parameter as a hidden input value into the form, so you can post it as a parameter to the back-end.

If you're using Node.js you just need to modify your `/third` view (might be a Jade / Pug template) 
to have

```
// Make sure this line is in the form that you're posting (syntax is jade - any other way of replacing the idFromServer value with a server value would work just as well.
input(name="id", type="hidden", value="#{idFromServer}")
```

and update your view render code to be like:

```
// It's read from query because we know this one is a get request.
res.render('third', {idFromServer: req.query.id});
```

After this `req.body.id` should work!
What we did here is whenever you're getting the third view with an id parameter, we'll put a hidden POST request field in the form. 
When you POST you can access your id variable because your form has an id field with a value. This is a common solution, but one thing to watch out is validating your query parameter because now you allowed people to randomly pass values onto your page - which will be posted back, you can never be sure that people won't pass some malicious values over there.

2. Another way of doing this - which I'm not recommending but it's a way - is to look into the headers. Because your current solution doesn't have the hidden form field - you can look into the [referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) header and your missing query parameter would be there.

You can just do a

```
console.log(req.headers.referer);
```

in your `/third` view and it should have the full previous URL which also contains the parameter you're looking for.

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you not recommend the second option?

Comment: It's a bad design - besides anyone who can post to that endpoint from another site (if CORS is enabled) / another desktop-client might break your referrer header - give you a completely unexpected value. Imagine you're expecting to see your domain.id/id=123 and you receive randomsite.net/x=mavi :)

Comment: The first option worked well and was explained clearly for a beginner like me, thanks a bunch!

Comment: :) Thanks - best of luck with NodeJs !